# Sveltekit hook not finding cookie on initial request

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a hook that gets a cookie and adds it to the session:

```
import { parse } from 'cookie';

export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
    const cookies = parse(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || "");

    event.locals.region = cookies.region;
    const response = await resolve(event);
    return response;
}

export const getSession = async (event) => {
    return {
        region: event.locals.region
    };
};
```

Then in my layout I have:

```
<script context="module">
    export const prerender = false;
    export async function load({params, fetch, session, stuff}) {
        return {
            props: {
                region: session.region
            }
        }
    }

</script>
<script>
export let region;
...
const updateRegion = (region) => {
        // this function is called by getPosition and sets the cookie.

        const d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + 120 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        document.cookie = `region=${region}; expires=${d}; path=/`;
    };

onMount(async () => {
        if (!region) {
            // I would assume this function never runs if the cookie is set 
            // getPosition is a function that calls a geocoder
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition, getPositionErr);
        } else {
            currentRegion.set(region);
            content.set(languages[$currentRegion]);
            regionSet = true;
        }
        pageLoading = false;
    });
```

As mentioned in the code, I would assume that if the browser has a cookie for the region we would never call the geocode function.  This is the case when I navigate from page to page in the app, but if I navigate away or refresh the page the region is reset, why is this?

Comment: How is the region cookie configured?

Comment: At the moment it's like zero configuration:  `document.cookie='region='${$currentRegion}';';`

Comment: I should mention... That everything works 100% locally but if I run a production build and refresh the website it's as if no cookie was set.

Comment: Are you setting the cookie in your code, is is it set somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah `getPosition` calls a function that sets it, I'll update the question.

Comment: This is messing up my webapp. A fresh page refresh will remove all the cookies and `hooks.server.ts` doesn't seem them right away. Did you come up with a solution?